# error message is not displayed in validation summary

Tags: asp.net

I have a following code on my web page.

```
table>
    <tr>
        <td class="style2"> <asp:ValidationSummary 
        ID="ValidationSummary1" 
        runat="server" 
        HeaderText="Following error occurs....." 
        ShowMessageBox="false" 
        DisplayMode="BulletList" 
        ShowSummary="true"
        BackColor="Snow"
        Width="200"
        ForeColor="Red"
        Font-Size="X-Large"
        Font-Italic="true" EnableClientScript="true" />
        </td>

    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" class="style2">
                Test1 : &nbsp;
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTest1" runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqTest1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlTest1" InitialValue="Please Select" ErrorMessage="Please Select Test1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>

            <td valign="top">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLocation" runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqLocation" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlLocation"  InitialValue="Please Select" ErrorMessage="Please select a Location"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

I am not getting any error message when I am clicking on submit button without selecting any dropdowns value. My dropdown code is

```
Private Sub Test1()
    ddlTest.DataSource = ' called the class to bid the drop down
  ddlTest.DataTextField = "Test"
    ddlTest.DataValueField = "Testid"
    ddlTest.DataBind()
    ddlTest.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Please Select", 0))

End Sub

Public Sub LoadLocation()
    ' ddlLocation.DataSource = ' called the class to bid the drop down


    ddlLocation.DataTextField = "location"
    ddlLocation.DataValueField = "id"
    ddlLocation.DataBind()
    ddlLocation.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Please Select", 0))
End Sub
```

Any help will be appreciated. I cannot see any error message when I click on submit button and the control gets transferred to the code behind of submit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Dropdown` validation is a little bit different.  You need to have `InitialValue` set in validator to verify and error out for non-selection

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqTest1" runat="server" InitialValue=0 ControlToValidate="ddlTest1" InitialValue="Please Select" ErrorMessage="Please Select Test1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

`InitialValue` is whatever value of the list item appears by default in the drop down.

It is also important to check `Page.IsValid` in your button click event, before you process anything.